# How to update 1 column only but to all rows with a calculation?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to update 1 column only for all rows in my table with the total calculation of :
The data of column multiply with random number between 0.9 to 1.2..

```
UPDATE TABLE
SET ABC = (SELECT ABC*(RAND()*((1.2-0.9)+0.9)) FROM TABLE)
```

Well idk how to write it in a proper T-SQL. I didn't get the expected result in SQL Server 2008 R2 with my query. Need your help guys to solve this things up. 
Or you can give me another solution with using cursor.

Comment: What other columns does your table have?

Comment: anyway the table is a Detail Table and resulted by Join of other 4 tables. And this table has no PK..
It contains of Date, PrdID, CstId, and CurrBalance.. 
The column that I want to calculate is the CurrBalance..

Comment: "*The column that I want to calculate is the CurrBalance*" - your example shows a column `abc` that is updated as formula based on only the contents of that column. Either your comment is wrong or you question.

Comment: yeah firstly I didn't want to give any detail of my table, and after Damien's question, I think it will be okay if just a name.. 
So CurrBalance is the column that I want to calculate..
And guys, I need a query that would give me the total calculation for each row, so the simple update query won't fixed this prob.
I need to make dummy data of thousands rows. And it is based on the CurrBalance*Random Number between 0.9-1.2..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE 
    @ABC_ID                        AS INT, 
    @RANDOM_GEN_NO    AS VARCHAR(50),
    @TEMP                        AS VARCHAR(50)

DECLARE ABC_CURSOR CURSOR FOR
SELECT @ABC_ID, RANDOM_GEN_NO FROM ABCTABLE FOR UPDATE OF RANDOM_GEN_NO
OPEN ABC_CURSOR
FETCH NEXT FROM ABC_CURSOR
INTO @EMP_ID, @RANDOM_GEN_NO

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    SELECT @TEMP =  ABC*(RAND()*((1.2-0.9)+0.9))
    UPDATE ABCTABLE SET ABC = @TEMP WHERE CURRENT OF ABC_CURSOR

    FETCH NEXT FROM ABC_CURSOR
    INTO @ABC_ID, @RANDOM_GEN_NO
END

CLOSE ABC_CURSOR
DEALLOCATE ABC_CURSOR

SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

OR IN Update Statement update ABCTable SET ABC = abc * yourcode

no need of select in update statement

Comment: That is *way* to complicated for a simple `update` statement - plus the cursor processing is going to be a **lot** slower than a plain update.

Comment: yeah i agree with that @user3812036 has been asking to fullfill his requirement using cursor so i ave given him otherwise simple update his enough

Comment: I think this is what I'm looking for..
I'll check it out and if it is solved, I'll be back for the thanks..

Comment: This solution is someone's post on the internet, but thanks anyway.
In the Code above there are some syntax error but once again Thank you sir..

Answer (score 2):

Think you have a problem of parenthesis (for the rand "range"), than the way to write the query (if I understood well)

```
update table
set abc = abc * (RAND() * (1.2-0.9) + 0.9)
```

**CAUTION**

the "random" multiplicator will be the same for all the rows updated by this statement, as noticed by Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: That deals with most of the issues other than the fact that `RAND()` will return the same value for every row, which I've assumed isn't the behaviour required (but prepared to be wrong)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever You're perfectly right, indeed, will add a CAUTION

Comment: Thanks for the help Raph. But yeah, the query gave me the same result to all rows, I'm looking for a query that would give me the total calculation for each row..

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE YourTABLE
SET ABC = ABC*(RAND()*((1.2-0.9)+0.9))
```

Comment: Think the rand's range won't be between 0.9 and 1.2 with this code (you have to add the low bound AFTER multiplication)

Answer (score 0):

ok from your code block I see several basic syntax errors. The basic syntax of an update statement is

```
UPDATE [Tablename] 
    SET [Columnname] = (Value or Calculation or subquery) 
    WHERE (condition)
```

For more information [check this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

UPDATE A
SET A.ABC = B.rand
from table A
inner join
(SELECT A.pkcolumn,A.ABC*(RAND()*((1.2-0.9)+0.9)) as rand FROM TABLE A)B
on A.pkcolumn = B.pkcolumn